# Exception while deploying my JPA-application to Websphere 7

Tags: java, deployment, jpa, websphere, eclipselink

I have problems deploying a web application to the most recent version of **IBM Websphere 7**.
The **exception** is caused during the JPA initialization.
The application is using **servlet 2.5, eclipselink 2.1.3**, java 6 update 25. 
persistence.xml is using version 1.0

I am **unsure**, if this exception is caused by a **bug/configuration error in Websphere** or by my application. Maybe it's also related to eclipselink.

**UPDATE**

Our application does not use JNDI for providing datasources to EclipseLink. Our application passes the DataSource directly to EclipseLink (using EclipseLink specific EntityManager properties)

The **persistence.xml** I am using is (leaving out all entity definitions and tuning properties):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
  version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source></non-jta-data-source>
    <class>my.applications.entity.classes.A</class>
    <!-- other class definitions follow -->
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />

      <!-- some other properties, not related to datasources/connections/JNDI 
        follow -->
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here comes the **System.err** output:

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.metadata.MetaDataException: CWWJP0018E: Incorrect syntax or error detected in /path/to/my/project/my_application_war.ear/my_application.war/WEB-INF/classes/ for application my_application_war module my_application.war. The following associated error occurred:
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAApplInfo.processModulePUs(JPAApplInfo.java:185)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.startingDeployedModule(JPAComponentImpl.java:895)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.stateChanged(JPAComponentImpl.java:748)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1075)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1302)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:221)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:607)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:726)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1268)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4588)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4766)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1273)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2045)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:441)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:655)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:617)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:244)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1074)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:955)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1332)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:239)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:564)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:353)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.InformationController.processForwardConfig(InformationController.java:217)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:933)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:321)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:557)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:607)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:984)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1069)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.metadata.MetaDataException: CWWJP0018E: Incorrect syntax or error detected in path/to/my/project/my_application_war.ear/my_application.war/WEB-INF/classes/ for application my_application_war module my_application.war. The following associated error occurred:
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPxmlInfo.extractPersistenceUnits(JPAPxmlInfo.java:449)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAScopeInfo.processPersistenceUnit(JPAScopeInfo.java:140)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAApplInfo.processModulePUs(JPAApplInfo.java:169)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getJPADataSource(JPAPUnitInfo.java:493)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getNonJtaDataSource(JPAPUnitInfo.java:577)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.createEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1314)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPxmlInfo.extractPersistenceUnits(JPAPxmlInfo.java:393)
    ... 92 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty non-jta-data-source is causing WebSphere Application Server to perform a lookup(""), which returns the root context, which it then attempts to cast to DataSource.

Container-managed JPA is designed for the container to acquire the data source and pass it to the EM itself.  I would recommend that you either specify your data source in persistence.xml, or just disable container-managed JPA altogether to avoid the error during application start:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM26361

Comment: I don't want to use container-managed JPA. I am using RESOURCE_LOCAL.

Comment: That setting is for container-managed JTA (i.e., how the JPA provider interacts with the transaction service), not how the container interacts with the JPA provider.  If the PM26361 document helped avoid the need for container-managed JPA, is there anything else you need before accepting the answer?

Comment: A non-jta-data-source isn't only for container managed JTA settings. It offers to set a DataSource by JNDI which can also be done by the application. As a workaround I had to include the tag to force EL to use a JNDIConnector to override its internal connection acquiring and allowed me to use my connection pool. However that tag causes problems in recent application servers (I don't see the problem in Websphere 6.1). I now set the JNDIConnector in my code so I was able to remove the tag.I'll accept you answer, because your hints were very helpful although not everything was correct. Thank you.

Comment: Per 8.2.1.5 of the JPA 2.0 spec, a data-source must be supplied in an EE environment that supports container-managed JPA.  WebSphere Application Server 6.1 (without the EJB3 feature pack) did not support container-managed JPA, so your persistence.xml was ignored.

Comment: That's correct. I think the problem here is that I defined "Java SE Environment" as an environment in which I am creating my EntityManager by myself (which is what I am doing) irrespective of if my application is deployed to an JEE container or not.However, it seems that this definition is not true or at least not fully defined in the JPA spec. So until now I thought that the third paragraph of the section you mentioned kicked in: "In Java SE environments, these elements may be used or the data source information may be specified
by other means—depending upon the requirements of the provider."

Comment: Right, in a JEE environment, the container has to call createContainerEntityManagerFactory very early during application startup in order to allow the provider to add ClassTransformers.  As part of that, WebSphere Application Server is acquiring a data-source to pass as part of the PersistenceUnitInfo.  So, in your case, the container is failing before it ever gets to your "Java SE"-like code.

Answer (score 2):

Websphere seems to be validating your data-source value in your persistence.xml, and it seems to be invalid.  You need to specify a valid value, even if you are overriding it later.

Please include your persistence.xml.  You could also try not setting a data-source, or using resource_local if it does not allow no data-source.

Comment: I've updated the questions which includes the persistence.xml. I am not setting a datasource, and I am using resource_local. But maybe the empty `<non-jta-data-source></non-jta-data-source>` is causing the problem? (but, btw: other application server do not have any problems with this web application)

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getJPADataSource(JPAPUnitInfo.java:493)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getNonJtaDataSource(JPAPUnitInfo.java:577)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.createEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1314)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPxmlInfo.extractPersistenceUnits(JPAPxmlInfo.java:393)
    ... 92 more
```

In your EAR config you have set a JNDI context where there should be a JNDI DataSource

Comment: Our application does not use JNDI for providing datasources to EclipseLink. Our application passes the DataSource directly to EclipseLink (using EclipseLink specific EntityManager properties). I've updated the question.